# How to delete the .swp files when working remotely

Tags: 12.04, gnome-terminal, remote-access, vi

I opened a file in vi, but unfortunately while changing it the terminal crashed. Now when I Try to open the same file again in a new session it displays the following message

```
E325: ATTENTION
Found a swap file by the name ".searchRefineVertTabs.jsp.swp"
          owned by: nextag   dated: Tue Mar  5 03:30:12 2013
         file name: ~nt/deploy/main/main.build.3616.BR_PS_1109.2239/..../searchRefineVertTabs.jsp
          modified: YES
         user name: nextag   host name: li1
        process ID: 9241
While opening file "searchRefineVertTabs.jsp"
             dated: Tue Mar  5 03:35:51 2013
      NEWER than swap file!

(1) Another program may be editing the same file.
    If this is the case, be careful not to end up with two
    different instances of the same file when making changes.
    Quit, or continue with caution.

(2) An edit session for this file crashed.
    If this is the case, use ":recover" or "vim -r searchRefineVertTabs.jsp"
    to recover the changes (see ":help recovery").
    If you did this already, delete the swap file ".searchRefineVertTabs.jsp.swp"
    to avoid this message.
```

I want to know how can i delete this .swp file. I couldn't find it on the path filepath/...../outpdir1`

Comment: Have you checked `~nextag/deploy/main/main.build.3616.BR_PS_1109.2239/www/seo/t1/buyer/outpdir1/` for that file?

Comment: yes i checked that, and that is what i mentioned in the last line

Comment: Edited my answer ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

During that alert you can press <kbd>D</kbd> . Or else have a look in your current directory in your local machine.

**Edit**:You can also search for the file with:

```
find | grep ".searchRefineVertTabs.jsp.swp"
```

Comment: I am accessing that file remotely, not locally

Comment: yeah, but with some configurations `.swp` file is stored localy

Comment: can you please elaborate. Tried using `D` it didn't work

Comment: the file was at the following path: `./.searchRefineVertTabs.jsp.swp` so used `rm ./.searchRefineVertTabs.jsp.swp`

Answer (score 0):

The .swp file will be generate at where your original file is there. SO just delete that file .

Suppose you have **file.txt** at **/usr/local/src/** , then your **.file.txt.swp** file will be create at **/usr/local/src/**.

just remove it then open open your original file. it wont give you options like readonly, edit etc